# Magento 2 Change Payment Method Codes

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am trying to change the payment method codes for `Paypal` and `M2E Pro`

The current method codes appear as `pro_hosted` and `m2epropayment` respectively.

I have tried to create a custom module to override the files the define these strings ,however, this did not work and prevented the payment methods from rendering.

Is there a better way this can be done, maybe through the database or another angle?

I have searched google but cannot seem to find a question relating to this.